# Срабатывает изменение размера окна TextInput только после 2 нажатия Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

У меня есть TextInput он обернут в ScrollView, а сам ScrollView обернут в GridLayout у которого size_hint = (1, .90). Так же у меня есть выпадающее меню кнопок на которых указан размер шрифта текста. Нажатие на которые вызывает такой метод

```
def sizeble(self, x):
        self.size_hint = (1, 1)
        self.font_size = x
        scroll_li() """Функция проверки начального текста. 
У меня там короткое сообщение и я проверяю сейчас текст 
открытый с помощью файлового менеджера или базовый"""

    def scroll_li():
        if self.text_input.text != "Hello Reader!\nPlease select a book and good reading!":
            self.text_input.size_hint = (1, None)
            self.text_input.size = (self.scroll.width, max( (len(self.text_input._lines)+1) * self.text_input.line_height, self.scroll.height, self.box_layout_for_text.height))
```

И это работает корректно, только после второго нажатия на изменение размера (та же самая кнопка)
Т.е. он изменяет шрифт и текст уходит за высоту TextInput.
Что я делаю не так?

Вот где я вызываю данные функции.

```
 dropdown_size.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: [sizeble(self.text_input, x)])
```

Я новичок в Kivy возможно я что-то упускаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось решение было  простым. Нужно было лишь в добавить вот такое вот событие для TextInput

```
self.text_input.bind(minimum_height=self.text_input.setter('height'))
```

и теперь все работает как нужно.